# Google drive not showing left panel

Tags: google-drive-shared-drive

I shared our coporate google drive folder with one of our suppliers but they are not seeing the left panel coming up so they can't add new files to the folder [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the client's company account forbids them from using drive.